# Lists within a Form - Dynamic Form

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have the following code with these drop down lists and even an autocomplete at the bottom. These are all built into form and work nicely until a keyboard is presented in iOS. Then I get the following error:

**Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.**

and this: **-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID **

I ran the backtrace but it looks like Chinese to me.. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
struct CreatePersonView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @ObservedObject var vm: EditPersonViewModel
    
    @State private var phoneDropDown = false
    @State private var emailDropDown = false
    @State private var hasError = false
    
    @State private var selectedLocation: MKMapItem?
    @State internal var searchResults: [MKMapItem] = []
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    @State internal var debounceTimer: Timer?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Form {
                Section("General") {
                    TextField("First Name", text: $vm.personEntity.firstName)
                        .keyboardType(.asciiCapable)
                    TextField("Last Name", text: $vm.personEntity.lastName)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                    TextField("Title", text: $vm.personEntity.title)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                }
                Section {
                    TextField("Cell", text: $vm.personEntity.mobile)
                        .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                    TextField("Phone", text: $vm.personEntity.phone1)
                        .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                    if phoneDropDown == true {
                        TextField("Fax", text: $vm.personEntity.fax)
                        TextField("Alternate Phone", text: $vm.personEntity.phone2)
                    }
                } header: {
                    phoneListHeader
                }
                Section {
                    TextField("Email", text: $vm.personEntity.email1)
                    if emailDropDown == true {
                        TextField("Email 2", text: $vm.personEntity.email2)
                        TextField("Email 3", text: $vm.personEntity.email3)
                    }
                } header: {
                    emailListHeader
                }
                if vm.hasOrg != true {
                    if selectedLocation == nil {
                        TextField("Add Location", text: $searchText)
                        List(searchResults.prefix(2), id: \.self) { item in
                            Button {
                                print(item)
                                handleSelection(item: item)
                                selectedLocation = item
                                searchResults = []
                            } label: {
                                AutoCompleteRow(item: item)
                                }
                            }
                    } else {
                        if let selectedLocation = selectedLocation {
                            AutoCompleteRow(item: selectedLocation)
                        } else {
                            Text("Error")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(vm.isNew ? "New Contact" : "Update Contact")
        .alert("Error", isPresented: $hasError, actions: {}) {
            Text("Please add a Name, City and State")
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction){
                Button("Done") {
                    validate()
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: searchText) {
            debounceSearch(query: searchText)
        }
    }
}
```

some of the private views pulled out

```
  private var phoneListHeader: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("Phone")
            Spacer()
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    phoneDropDown.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("More")
                    .font(.caption)
                Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: phoneDropDown ? 180 : 0))
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var emailListHeader: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("E-mail")
            Spacer()
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    emailDropDown.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("More")
                    .font(.caption)
                Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: emailDropDown ? 180 : 0))
            }
        }
    }
```

** And the backtrace **

```
Backtrace:
  <CGPathAddLineToPoint+88>
   <+[UIBezierPath _continuousRoundedRectBezierPath:withRoundedCorners:cornerRadii:segments:smoothPillShapes:]+1736>
    <+[UIBezierPath _continuousRoundedRectBezierPath:withRoundedCorners:cornerRadius:segments:]+180>
     <+[UIBezierPath _roundedRectBezierPath:withRoundedCorners:cornerRadius:segments:legacyCorners:]+340>
      <-[_UITextChoiceAccelerationBubble backgroundImageView]+156>
       <-[_UITextChoiceAccelerationBubble anchorToTextIfNeeded]+500>
        <-[_UITextChoiceAccelerationBubble updateTextAnchorForParentView:]+156>
         <-[_UITextChoiceAccelerationBubble updateTextBoxHighlightForRect:inTextView:parentView:highlightColor:]+88>
          <-[_UITextChoiceAccelerationAssistant updateActivePromptForCandidate:displayRects:highlightOnly:]+352>
           <-[UIKeyboardImpl updateAutocorrectPrompt:correctionRects:]+492>
            <-[UIKeyboardImpl updateAutocorrectPrompt:executionContext:]+608>
             <__45-[UIKeyboardImpl touchAutocorrectPromptTimer]_block_invoke+112>
              <__56-[UIKeyboardScheduledTask handleDeferredTimerFiredEvent]_block_invoke+184>
               <-[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:]+200>
                <-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread]+304>
                 <-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue addTask:]+92>
                  <-[UIKeyboardScheduledTask handleDeferredTimerFiredEvent]+216>
                   <__invoking___+144>
                    <-[NSInvocation invoke]+276>
                     <-[_UIActionWhenIdle invoke]+52>
                      <__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__+32>
                       <__CFRunLoopDoObservers+528>
                        <__CFRunLoopRun+968>
                         <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+572>
                          <GSEventRunModal+160>
                           <-[UIApplication _run]+868>
                            <UIApplicationMain+124>
                             <OUTLINED_FUNCTION_70+500>
                              <OUTLINED_FUNCTION_70+148>
                               <OUTLINED_FUNCTION_2+92>
                                <$s6Klatch0A3AppV5$mainyyFZ+40>
                                 <main+12>
                                  101039558
                                   1010de0e0                                    2d60000000000000
```

[image]